# Extjs Radio Group: Can only click on one item

Tags: extjs, radio-group

I'm not even sure how to search for this, so hopefully this hasn't already been answered a hundred times.

Basically, I have a radio group on my form with three options: Show Completed Exams, Show Incomplete Exams, or Show All Exams.

```
{
name:           'ShowComplete',
fieldLabel:     'Show',
allowBlank:     true,
columns:        1,
items:          [
                    {
                        name:           'ShowComplete',
                        boxLabel:       'Completed Exams',
                        inputValue:     '1'
                    }, 
                    {
                        name:           'ShowComplete',
                        boxLabel:       'Incomplete Exams',
                        inputValue:     '0'
                    }, 
                    {
                        name:           'ShowComplete',
                        boxLabel:       'All',
                        inputValue:     '-1'
                    }
                ],
xtype:          'radiogroup'
}
```

When I load the page, I have a nice looking control.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/298258/extJSRadioGroup.png

However, the only one I can select is *Incomplete Exams*.

Is there something I am missing? I'm sure it's something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed that if I take the middle item out, it works perfectly.  I don't see anything about it that looks out of place, so I'm now even more confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue.
I believe it is related to the fact you're giving the value '0' to your middle item.

Perhaps, due to Javascript's nature, it is afterward wrongly interpreted as 'false' or something like that and causes the behavior of the radio buttons to break.

If you replace the '0' by anything else, it should work.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, thank you. I changed the values to True, False and NULL.  Unfortunately, this correlates with a bit field in my stored procedure, so I'll have to do some conversion to get it working.  If I ever find a workaround for this, I'll post it here.

Comment: It's exactly the same issue I had... I was attempting to map the field's value with the database's value, but I had to change it to a Java enumeration's name. I'll have to be on the lookout for the next time...

Comment: Experiencing the same problem now. Thanks for solution

Comment: 3 years later, I face the same problem. If it were not for this solution, it would have taken me another 3 years to solve it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the `name` attribute off the RadioGroup... perhaps it is conflicting?

Comment: `name` *should* be given, and should be the same, and you need to have same `name` in each of the radio button so they will act as one group of radio buttons, and hence only one radio button is clickable at a time. Cheers